# Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I have a problem connecting my url to my quorum node.

I already make sure the node has an account, I run it without problem but I have that error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the cors domain isn't correct, you'd need to enter the url of remix in there. We have a detailed presentation that talk about how to do this in some detail here:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1vMBVKTJyKbGwZaMqwxA7VaCTEXELA5kLf56byZIbD3g

Comment: What I want to do is connect to the node that is made with quorum and deploy the smart contract to use it with nethereum.

Comment: but thank you very much for the information I'm checking ..